Solving the system $m+n= 6$, $mn + p + q= 9$, $mq + np = -4$, $pq= -12$
If $m,n,p,q$ are four distinct real numbers satisfying the system of equations:
$$\begin{align}
m+n &= 6 \\
mn + p + q &= 9 \\
mq + np &= -4 \\
pq &= -12
\end{align}$$
Then, solve for $m,n,p,q \in R$.
Using all $4$ equations, we get $(m+p+1)(n+q+1) = 0$.
I'm not sure where to go from this besides the case analysis.
Please help me out with this problem. Thank you!

Major hint: Generalize your observation much much more. Factorize $ \color{white} {x^4 + 6x^3 + 9x^2 - 4x - 12 =0}$. Highlight text to read.

@abomasnow, its the multiplication symbol.

I'll change it, sorry.

Notice that each of these equations may correspond to the coefficient of different powers in the polynomial: $$(x^2+mx+p)(x^2+nx+q)$$ Expanding this results in $$x^4+(m+n)x^3+(mn+p+q)x^2 + (mq+np)x + pq$$ Replacing each of these terms with the equations we are given yields: $$x^4+6x^3+9x^2-4x-12$$ This is easily factorable to $$(x+3)(x-1)(x+2)(x+2)$$ Now, we must find a way to choose two pairs from these $4$ terms to combine into our $2$ quadratics. There are only $3$ options:

Combine (x+2) and (x+2)
Combine (x+2) and (x+3)
Combine (x-1) and (x+2)

Option $1$ will make one quadratic equivalent to $x^2+4x+4$, and this would mean two of our variables would be $4$, contradicting the fact that each $m,n,p,q$ are distinct.
Option $2$ and Option $3$ are actually equivalent, since each is a mirror of the other. These will set one quadratic to $x^2+5x+6$ and the other to $x^2+x-2$. So, substituting our variables for our coefficients gives us two unique answers:
$$m=5\\n=1\\p=6\\q=-2$$
or
$$m=1\\n=5\\p=-2\\q=6$$

@abomasnow Did you see the part where I reasoned why Option 1 won't work? That case is technically correct, but each variable has to be distinct, and there can't be duplicate 4's.
